# How do you "Sign In with Google" with NextJS and Firebase Auth on Safari

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm using:

- firebase: ^8.6.8
- next: ^11.0.1
- react: ^17.0.2

When trying to sign in with Google on Safari, I get errors related to a Content Blocker with both **signInWithPopUp** and **signInWithRedirect**:

```sh
Content blocker prevented frame displaying https://my-site.com/page
from loading a resource from https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb318667
```

Does anybody know how to handle this properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the solution I used:

Instead of using `signInWithRedirect` or `signInWithPopup` that seem to cause problem on Apple devices using Safari, I directly use [`https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js`] and then `signInWithCredential` using the `googleUser`.

I also used the package `react-google-signin` [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login] to simplify my code.

Step by step:

1. Enable Google Sign-in  method on Firebase Console for Authentication
2. On the Credentials page of Google Cloud Platform [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials], choose your project and under **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** get the Client Id.
3. Save the Client ID as an environment variable `NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` in your Project Settings on Vercel.
4. In your `_document.tsx` add the `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` script and needed meta data:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}></meta>
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin"></meta>
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email"></meta>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

5. Define your Google Sign in button:

```
const GoogleButton: FC<GoogleButtonProps> = ({onSuccess, onFailure}) => {
  const onSignInFailure = (failure: any) => {
    console.error('FAILURE: ', failure);
    onFailure(...);
  };
  const onSignIn = (googleUser: any) => {
    signInWithGoogleUser(googleUser)
     .then(onSuccess)
     .catch(onFailure);
  }

  return (
    <GoogleLogin
      render={(renderProps) => (
        <button
          onClick={renderProps.onClick}
          disabled={renderProps.disabled}>
            This is my custom Google button
        </button>
      )}
      clientId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!}
      buttonText="Login"
      onSuccess={onSignIn}
      onFailure={onSignInFailed}
      cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
      prompt="select_account"
    />
  );
};
```

I specified `prompt="select_account"` to be sure it prompt the user for the account selection even if hse is already logged in.

6. Then, inside signInWithGoogleUser, is use `signInWithCredential` to use the `googleUser` to authentify on Firebase Auth:

```
export const signInWithGoogleUser = (googleUser: any) => {
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
  const credential = provider.credential(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
  return auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
};
```

**NOTES**

a. My project is running on Vercel [https://vercel.com/] with the Database (Firestore) and Authentication on Firebase [https://firebase.com]. You will have to adapt my solution if you use another stack.

b. With this, it works on almost all iPhones and Mac computers. In case it still fails, it is due to an installed content/cookie blocker and I display an error message asking the visitor to reactivate cookies or register using email and password.

c. I simplified a bit the code to have a more condensed answer.